# Hosting static HTML in a Play! app on CloudFront

Tags: playframework, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a (high-traffic) chunk of my website that is entirely static.  All the site's URLs are relative, so right now it all works if I just point my browser to `http://gj232j2j213.cloudfront.net/blah`.

I'd like to host the entire thing (not just images and css, but the HTML too) on Cloudfont (or some other CDN).

Ideally, I could put something like:

```
GET    /static/    staticDir:http://gj232j2j213.cloudfront.net/blah
```

in my routes file.  That way my URLs would look like `www.mydomain.com/static/main.html`, and I wouldn't have to bounce the user to a different subdomain as they moved back and forth between my static and non-static URLs.

Any ideas?  Am I misguided?

Comment: I'm working on adding correct headers into Play 2 so that you can use it as an origin server for transparent CloudFront caching.  Check out: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/276

Comment: Awesome!  I'm on 1.2.4 for now, and I also don't have any real traffic for now :-/.  So maybe I'll just serve them straight from my app for now, and I'll get my act together for 2.0 when/if it gets expensive using Heroku instead of CloudFront to serve static content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the following in my `conf/routes` file to do this:

```
# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
#{if play.Play.mode.isDev()}
    GET     /public/                        staticDir:public
#{/}
#{else}
    GET     d2iu8jbjgczc8x.cloudfront.net/public  staticDir:public
    GET     /public/                              staticDir:public
#{/}
```

Then you just reference the static assets the normal way and the URLs will use the CloudFront server (in Prod mode).

Comment: Does this work in Play 1.2.4, or is it Play 2.x only?  Does it require the patch you mentioned above?

Comment: I ask because it is not working for me in 1.2.4.  No compile error, it just isn't redirecting to cloudfront.

Comment: This is Play 1.2.x only.  Are you running in prod mode?  If you view source did it create the URLs to CloudFront?

Comment: I am running in prod mode, but I think I might see my misunderstanding.  I am using raw HTML to reference my stylesheets, and I'm guessing you must be using the template engine somehow.  `href="@{/public/stylesheets/main.css}"` is a compile error for me...  How do you reference stylesheets using the template/routing engine?  And how do you get your stylesheets to use the template engine to reference images?

Comment: Ah, yes.  It would be: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@@{'/public/stylesheets/index.css'}">`  I'm not sure about URLs in the stylesheet.  If they are relative to where the stylesheet came from then this is easy.  If they are relative to the page they are loaded in, then it's going to be tough.

Comment: Looks like they are relative to where the stylesheet came from.  So you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Could never get this to work in Play 2.x.

```
GET     /public/      staticDir:public
```

What worked for me is something like this.

```
GET  /somefile.html   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="somefile.html")
```