# CDN usages on Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a high traffic website with a lot of static content.  It is currently on Play 1.2.4 but  I am doing the migration to Play 2.0.2.

For Play 1.X we wrote some code that we used instead of the @asset inside of html templates.

```
/**
 * Drop-in replacement for @asset. Use to take advantage of cloudfront on live.
 * Paths are always absolute to root. Leading '/' is optional.
 *
 * @param path relative to the application root. This should usually be "public/some-file"
 * @return path to asset on the currently configured CDN.
 */
def cdnAsset(path: String) : String = {
  cdnEnabled match {
    case "true" =>
      path(0) match {
        case '/' => "https://" + cdnUrl + path
        case _ =>  "https://" + cdnUrl + "/" + path
      }

    case _ =>
        play.mvc.Router.reverse(play.Play.getVirtualFile(path))
  }
}
```

For Play 2.0 I think we can improve upon this.  I think it would be better if we didn't have to litter our templates with our custom code instead of using the the @Asset.at provided by Play 2.0.  I not sure the best way to do this.  I wondering if doing something like was done in the answer to this question on Play 1.2.X 
[Hosting static HTML in a Play! app on CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524285/hosting-static-html-in-a-play-app-on-cloudfront)
could be done for Play 2.0.

I would like to take full advantage of the Assets controller provided by Play 2.0 since it performs a few optimizations that would be nice to have.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?  I'm thinking if it can be done with just some Router magic, that would be ideal but I'm still a little too beginner with Play to know if or how that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James Ward has written an [excellent tutorial](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/08/edge-caching-with-play2-heroku-cloudfront) to do it cleanly.

Comment: This tutorial looks good.  It's too mad no one has made this into a plugin yet.  I'll have to consider doing that.

Comment: Good idea ! that will be a useful quite small plugin.

Comment: I have just [started to work](https://github.com/mchv/play2-cloudfront) on it. A small plug-in inspired by the James tutorial. I will let you know when its operational.

Comment: Awesome, I'm excited.  I still need to finish migrating my app over to Play 2 before I can use it.  I'll check it out when it's ready though.

Comment: Hey, any update on that plugin?  I've finally migrated enough of my site that I can test it out.

Comment: I just released the very first version. Please let me know if something does not work as expected. The module is really tiny, basically it prevents you to write and maintain ten or so lines. By the way it should work with any other CDN provider.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I have actually written my own Plugin while I was waiting on yours.  It works a little differently since you don't have to write any code to use it since I do some hackery to make a controller available.  https://github.com/ChazInc/play-cdn